# How to filter data based on value in input field using react and javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have the data like below,

const data = [
{
"id":200,
"description":"Substitute",
"start date":"1990-12-
28T00:00:00+00:00"
},
{
"id":1,
"description":"some description",
"start date":"2013-06-28T00:00:00+00:00"
}
],

i initially get this data from doing a fetch to an api and i store it in data state and display it in a table with id, description and start_date fields in the table like below,

[image]

there is an input field to search for description and id. if user enters a value in the input field, it should filter the data in the table that matches with description or id.

so for example if user enters the string 'Substitute' it should return data related to the matched description like below,

[image]

Now if user enters the id say 1 then it should return data related to the matched id like below,
[image]

my code is like below,

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: [],
            query: "",
            filtered_data: [],
        };
    }
   
    get_data = () => {
        fetch(proxyurl + url, {
            method:'get',
            headers: {'Content-type':'application/json','Cache-Control': 'no-cache'}, //api to get 
            //the data
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
        const { query } = this.state;
        const filtered_data = data.filter(element => {
            return element.name.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase());
        })
        this.setState({
            data,
            filtered_data
        });
    });
};

handle_change = e => {
    const query = e.target.value;

    this.setState(prevState => {
        const filtered_data = prevState.data.filter(element => {
            return element.name.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase());
        });

        return {
            query,
            filtered_data
        };
    });
};

componentDidMount(){
    this.get_data();
}

render() {
    return (
        <>
            {this.state.filtered_data &&
                <>
                    <div>
                        <label></label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Filter Table" value={this.state.query} 
                        onChange={this.handle_change}/>
                    </div>
                    <Table
                        data={this.state.filtered_data}
                    />
                </>
      
            }
        </>
    )
}
```

};

this gives me an error like

"Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined"

not sure how to fix this. i am learning react and javascript. could someone help me with this. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't have any key named `name` in your element object. (that you get returned from your api ) as a result when you are trying to perform `element.name.toLowerCase()` the name is undefined and so you get this error.

if you want to filter based on the value of description you can do something like this

`element.description.toLowerCase()`